# Ocultar campo en angular si se cumple una condición

Tags: angular, material

Tengo un formulario y quiero que cuando en procesador se ingresa "clon", el campo modelo se oculte o deshabilite.

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
    <input 
      placeholder="Procesador" 
      matInput 
      name="Procesador" 
      formControlName="Procesador" 
      >
    <mat-error *ngIf="serverForm.get('model').hasError('required')">
      Debe ingresar un procesador
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field fxFlex>
    <input 
      placeholder="Modelo" 
      matInput 
      name="model" 
      formControlName="model" 
      >
    <mat-error *ngIf="serverForm.get('model').hasError('required')">
      Debe ingresar un modelo
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

El procesador por default va a ser clon o intel, cuando se señale la opción clon quiero que se deshabilite el modelo, o se oculte. 
Alguien sabe como podría resolverlo? gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir la directiva `ngIf` para controlar la visibilidad del campo `Procesador`. La directiva `*ngIf` no oculta el campo sino que no lo renderiza en el `DOM`.

En tu componente ts

```
// luego de crear el formulario
procesador: FormControl = this.form.get('Procesador');
```

En template html

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
    <input 
      placeholder="Procesador" 
      matInput 
      name="Procesador" 
      formControlName="Procesador" 
      >
    <mat-error *ngIf="serverForm.get('model').hasError('required')">
      Debe ingresar un procesador
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field fxFlex *ngIf="procesador.value !== 'clone'">
    <input 
      placeholder="Modelo" 
      matInput 
      name="model" 
      formControlName="model" 
      >
    <mat-error *ngIf="serverForm.get('model').hasError('required')">
      Debe ingresar un modelo
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Si quieres ponerlo `disabled` tendrás puedes usar el método `disabled` de `FormControl`. Para eso tendrás que subscribirte a los cambios del input para ver el valor que contiene y aplicar el `disabled`.

```
procesador.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
   if (val === 'clone') {
     this.form.get('modelo').disable();
   }
});
```

[Documentación](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#updating-parts-of-the-data-model) reactive forms